# Python convert a list of strings in a nested list to list

Tags: python, list, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a variable called last_price which outputs:

```
                              SPY
Date                             
2015-02-02 00:00:00+00:00  201.92
```

I want to extend last_price to a shape of 1000,1 using the following code:

```
lp_list=[]
lp_len=np.ones(1000)
for o in lp_len:
    p=last_price
    lp_list.append(p)
```

but print lp_list outputs:

```
[                              SPY
Date                             
2015-02-02 00:00:00+00:00  201.92,                               SPY
Date                             
2015-02-02 00:00:00+00:00  201.92,                               SPY
Date                             
2015-02-02 00:00:00+00:00  201.92
etc...
```

Regardless of what my final end use is, how can I convert lp_list to a flat list of the price string only (201.92)?

When I try to flatted using a list comprehension I get the following:

```
>>flat_lp = [y for x in lp_list for y in x]
>>print flat_lp
...['SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY',     'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY', 'SPY',
etc...
```

Is there a way that I can create a flat list of just last_price variable with output of 201.92, repeated 1000 times, such as in the below:

```
>>print lp_list
...[201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92,
etc...
```

Two things to consider:

1) last_price is a dataframe type:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

2) The elements in lp_list need to be float type integer

Thanks

Comment: Can you add to your question the example of what your desired output is?  You say in words, but it would be easier to see.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the desired output and two additional thoughts to consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to repeat your price you can just use `itertool.repeat` , so you dont need loops , you can split the string then pick the last element with `[-1]` indexing :

```
>>> s="""                              SPY
... Date                             
... 2015-02-02 00:00:00+00:00  201.92"""
>>> s.split()
['SPY', 'Date', '2015-02-02', '00:00:00+00:00', '201.92']
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> repeat(s.split()[-1],10)
repeat('201.92', 10)
>>> list(repeat(float(s.split()[-1]),10))
[201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92, 201.92]
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert s.split()[-1] to a float prior to repeating?

Comment: @molivizzy yes , you need to use `float` function , checkout the edit